# Asp.Net mvc create new record in Jquery dialog cache

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog, cache-control

I have an invoice page where I can stock-out a product to a customer. While I am typing the customer name in textbox, I am using autocomplete to find names. If name doesn't exist, I show a button "Add New" with Json request.
This button shows an iframe in Jquery Dialog.

```
<div id="dialogDiv" style="display:none" class="ui-dialog">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="450" height="500"
 src='@Url.Action("Create_Modal","Customers",new { date=DateTime.Now})'></iframe></div>
```

When I add new customer. I return another View inside

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create_Modal()
{
    //saving the record
    return View("Create_OK")
}
```

Create_OK View just shows a success message.
Everything is fine till I close and re-open the Dialog. It just shows the success message (not the create form). 
I want it to show Create_Modal() View to add another record.
I tried these:

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
$('#dialogDiv').html(""); //after this. Nothing is shown in dialog anymore.
```

I added these to head:

```
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
    <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0">
```

And I also add this to Create_Modal() Get Controller

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

How can I clear the dialog/iframe cache and see the create form whenever I click the button?
P.S This is not duplicate of anything. Because I've also tried all of the related answers.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

I solved it with adding iframe src attr from js

```
function openDialog() {
    var ifURL = '@Url.Action("Create_Modal", "Customers", new { date = DateTime.Now })';
    $('#ifDialog').attr("src", ifURL);
    $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 550,
        width: 500,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        resizable: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $('#dialogDiv').dialog('close'); 
            }
        }

    });
    $('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
}
```

But I still can not close the dialog with the button inside View. There is a Close button under success message.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="closeDialog()" value="Close" />
```

And js code

```
@section scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeDialog() {
    $('#dialogDiv').dialog('close');
}
</script>
```

}

But this is not working for me.

Comment: why are you using an iframe?

Comment: To be able to stay in same page (in dialog modal) after post and create new customer. I need to show a success message.

Comment: iframes are for showing content hosted on another domain, there is no need for an iframe here , you can just show a success message

Comment: yes but it is not only to show success message. First show create form in Jquery dialog, after posting the form I show the response. Error or success messages in same modal dialog. I couldn't do it with divs or partial views etc.

Comment: why not , you can mainpulate the HTML in anyway you want with javascript.  The whole purpose of iframes are when you can't control what is in the iframe because it came from another domain - and you want that displayed on your page